# Amazon MWS listMatchingProducts more than 10 results?

Tags: java, amazon-mws

I integrated amazons mws using java and Im able to use `listMatchingProducts`. When I send a query I just get 10 results back. In the documentations I found something about using the `nextToken` but I dont see how.
I will appreciate some help here.

**Edit**:

It seems there is no `nextToken` coming with the results:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ListMatchingProductsResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
<ListMatchingProductsResult>
  <Products xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01" xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd">
    <Product>
      <Identifiers>
        <MarketplaceASIN>
          <MarketplaceId>A1PA6795UKMFR9</MarketplaceId>
          <ASIN>B005CNZN7A</ASIN>
        </MarketplaceASIN>
      </Identifiers>
      <AttributeSets>
        <ns2:ItemAttributes xml:lang="de-DE">
          <ns2:AspectRatio>2.40:1</ns2:AspectRatio>
          <ns2:AudienceRating>Freigegeben ab 12 Jahren</ns2:AudienceRating>
          <ns2:Binding>DVD</ns2:Binding>
          <ns2:Brand>RADCLIFFE DANIEL</ns2:Brand>
          <ns2:Creator Role="Darsteller">Daniel Radcliffe</ns2:Creator>
          <ns2:Creator Role="Hauptdarsteller">Daniel Radcliffe</ns2:Creator>
          <ns2:Creator Role="Darsteller">Emma Watson</ns2:Creator>
          <ns2:Creator Role="Hauptdarsteller">Emma Watson</ns2:Creator>
          <ns2:Creator Role="Darsteller">Rupert Grint</ns2:Creator>
          <ns2:Creator Role="Autor">Joanne K. Rowling</ns2:Creator>
          <ns2:Creator Role="Komponist">Alexandre Desplat</ns2:Creator>
          <ns2:Creator Role="Regisseur">David Yates</ns2:Creator>
          <ns2:Feature>Medium: DVD</ns2:Feature>
          <ns2:Feature>Regie: David Yates</ns2:Feature>
          <ns2:Feature>Laufzeit: ca. 125 Minuten</ns2:Feature>
          <ns2:Feature>Label: Warner Home Entertainment</ns2:Feature>
          <ns2:Feature>Bildformat: 2.40:1</ns2:Feature>
          <ns2:Format>Dolby</ns2:Format>
          <ns2:Format>PAL</ns2:Format>
          <ns2:Format>Widescreen</ns2:Format>
          <ns2:IsAdultProduct>false</ns2:IsAdultProduct>
          <ns2:IsEligibleForTradeIn>true</ns2:IsEligibleForTradeIn>
          <ns2:Label>Warner Home Video - DVD</ns2:Label>
          <ns2:Languages>
            <ns2:Language>
              <ns2:Name>german</ns2:Name>
              <ns2:Type>Untertitel für Hörgeschädigte</ns2:Type>
            </ns2:Language>
            <ns2:Language>
              <ns2:Name>english</ns2:Name>
              <ns2:Type>Untertitel für Hörgeschädigte</ns2:Type>
            </ns2:Language>
            <ns2:Language>
              <ns2:Name>french</ns2:Name>
              <ns2:Type>Subtitled</ns2:Type>
            </ns2:Language>
            <ns2:Language>
              <ns2:Name>dutch</ns2:Name>
              <ns2:Type>Subtitled</ns2:Type>
            </ns2:Language>
            <ns2:Language>
              <ns2:Name>german</ns2:Name>
              <ns2:Type>Original</ns2:Type>
            </ns2:Language>
            <ns2:Language>
              <ns2:Name>english</ns2:Name>
              <ns2:Type>Original</ns2:Type>
            </ns2:Language>
            <ns2:Language>
              <ns2:Name>french</ns2:Name>
              <ns2:Type>Original</ns2:Type>
            </ns2:Language>
            <ns2:Language>
              <ns2:Name>dutch</ns2:Name>
              <ns2:Type>Original</ns2:Type>
            </ns2:Language>
          </ns2:Languages>
          <ns2:ListPrice>
            <ns2:Amount>12.99</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:CurrencyCode>EUR</ns2:CurrencyCode>
          </ns2:ListPrice>
          <ns2:Manufacturer>Warner Home Video - DVD</ns2:Manufacturer>
          <ns2:NumberOfItems>1</ns2:NumberOfItems>
          <ns2:PackageDimensions>
            <ns2:Height Units="inches">0.63</ns2:Height>
            <ns2:Length Units="inches">7.48</ns2:Length>
            <ns2:Width Units="inches">5.28</ns2:Width>
            <ns2:Weight Units="pounds">0.13</ns2:Weight>
          </ns2:PackageDimensions>
          <ns2:PartNumber>WH 1000239545</ns2:PartNumber>
          <ns2:ProductGroup>DVD</ns2:ProductGroup>
          <ns2:ProductTypeName>ABIS_DVD</ns2:ProductTypeName>
          <ns2:Publisher>Warner Home Video - DVD</ns2:Publisher>
          <ns2:RegionCode>2</ns2:RegionCode>
          <ns2:ReleaseDate>2011-11-18</ns2:ReleaseDate>
          <ns2:RunningTime Units="minutes">125</ns2:RunningTime>
          <ns2:SmallImage>
            <ns2:URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51xgZdaZIBL._SL75_.jpg</ns2:URL>
            <ns2:Height Units="pixels">75</ns2:Height>
            <ns2:Width Units="pixels">53</ns2:Width>
          </ns2:SmallImage>
          <ns2:Studio>Warner Home Video - DVD</ns2:Studio>
          <ns2:TheatricalReleaseDate>2011-01-01</ns2:TheatricalReleaseDate>
          <ns2:Title>Harry Potter und die Heiligtümer des Todes (Teil 2)</ns2:Title>
        </ns2:ItemAttributes>
      </AttributeSets>
      <Relationships/>
      <SalesRankings>
        <SalesRank>
          <ProductCategoryId>dvd_display_on_website</ProductCategoryId>
          <Rank>18</Rank>
        </SalesRank>
        <SalesRank>
          <ProductCategoryId>3120191</ProductCategoryId>
          <Rank>1</Rank>
        </SalesRank>
        <SalesRank>
          <ProductCategoryId>289094</ProductCategoryId>
          <Rank>2</Rank>
        </SalesRank>
        <SalesRank>
          <ProductCategoryId>290505</ProductCategoryId>
          <Rank>3</Rank>
        </SalesRank>
      </SalesRankings>
    </Product>
    <Product>
    ...
    </Product>
</ListMatchingProductsResult>
<ResponseMetadata>
  <RequestId>623b3da9-733d-48c6-a535-a7f9da6ea525</RequestId>
</ResponseMetadata>
</ListMatchingProductsResponse>
```

Comment: You have to send a followup request with a `nextToken` field set to whatever value you received as a response to your last request. That will get you the next 10 items, and possibly another nextToken field (if there are still more matching products). Keep on 'chain-requesting' this way until you do not get a `nextToken` in the response.

Comment: thx but could you give me some example code? Im a little bit confused about this.

Comment: The link below is your best bet for information on nextToken, However I don't believe this is possible as I do not see a "nextToken" or "HasNext" from the ListMatchingProducts response. Also there is no method named ListMatchignProductsByNextToken .

https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/bde/MWSDeveloperGuide._V386854335_.pdf

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the documentation of MWS, the product API returns only 10 items, so there is no `nextToken` available. See documentation:
http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetMatchingProduct.html

A picture from the documentation:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a83tY.png

Answer (score 0):

The [ListMatchingProducts](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_ListMatchingProducts.html) operation performs a search based on your criteria and does not provide a nextToken like some of the other operations.  Try using [GetMatchingProductForId](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetMatchingProductForId.html) which is the recommended approach if you have an ASIN or SKU.  But if you need to perform a search using ListMatchingProducts, you're stuck with what you get in your initial request which is a maximum of ten results.

Comment: Then what is the recommended way to search products in Amazon? Is there any API inside MWS or any other API? The question is how I can search for "harry potter dvd" and can get all the search results?